# Automation Process for Website PHP PostgreSQL

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

Currently, I'm working with a website. This website is written using PHP with PostgreSQL as the back-end. For the server I use Apache (XAMPP). My website has a membership feature consist of free membership and premium membership. Premium membership valid for 1 year after the registration, after that the user membership will be revert back to free membership. To be a premium membership again, the user should pay the membership fee and the account will be upgraded again for the next 1 year (imagine Rapidshare membership!). How to create a automation process to check and demote an expired membership? I think it should be a background process working on the back-end (postgresql), but I'm not really sure. Any idea or solution?

Big thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be like this:

- User pays for premium
- Script inserts an entry in a database with premium cancelling dates, with cancelling date and user FK
- A daily [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)/[at](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true)(depending on OS) job searches the db for cancelling dates with the date of today, and cancels the respective users' premium membership

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hmm, but how can I make it when the web hosting is not on my office? I used 3rd party web hosting. Though I paid for its service, I'm afraid that they don't give me privilege  to access their cron...

Comment: @GuyFreakz If you can't do this, you could try something like in jmz's answer

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server have an ability to handle background process. I was once read an online article about someone delete inactive member account from his database automatically, but I forget, where I read it. For now, I've done what jmz suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a table schema like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE all_accounts (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    premium_expires DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT current_date,
    other_attrs,
    ...
);
```

Then create a view which you use for queries:

```
CREATE VIEW accounts AS
SELECT
   account.*, current_date < account.premium_expires AS is_premium_membership
FROM
   account
WHERE 
   id = ?
```

Now a select to `accounts` will yield an `is_premium_membership` attribute which is `t` when  the premium membership is valid. No need for background jobs.

Comment: For now, that's what I did ;p

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check every time when user logs in?

Comment: well what if the user stays logged in for two weeks or so? I know I haven't logged out of gmail (for example) for 1 month or so